# Parse output of command and save it to a list

Tags: erlang

I want to parse the result of command and save it to a list:

```
Process Pid Mello       No  Status
122     523 GFAF_0      1   Running
125     512 GFAF_235    2   Running
128     987 GFAF_1      3   Stopped
```

Expected output:

```
[GFAF_0,GFAF_235,GFAF_1]
```

I want to regex by `GFAF_XYZ` (where `XYZ` are numbers) but I can't find a way to do that.

Regards,
Damian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feeel that you are looking something similar to [getopt](https://github.com/jcomellas/getopt)

You need to specify options acording to your input format

```
OptSpecList =
    [
     {host,    $h,        "host",    {string, "localhost"}, "Database server host"},
     {port,    $p,        "port",    integer,               "Database server port"},
     {dbname,  undefined, "dbname",  {string, "users"},     "Database name"},
     {xml,     $x,        undefined, undefined,             "Output data in XML"},
     {verbose, $v,        "verbose", integer,               "Verbosity level"},
     {file,    undefined, undefined, string,                "Output file"}
    ].
```

and then call to `getopt:parse/2:`

```
getopt:parse(OptSpecList, ["-h", "myhost", "--port=1000", "-x", "file.txt", "-vvv", "dummy1", "dummy2"]).
```

You will get the tuple

```
{ok,{[{host,"myhost"},
      {port,1000},
      xml,
      {file,"file.txt"},
      {dbname,"users"},
      {verbose,3}],
     ["dummy1","dummy2"]}}
```

OR supersimple solution

if you receive data as string for example

```
"Process Pid Mello No Status 122 523 GFAF_0 1 Running 125 512 GFAF_235 2 Running 128 987 GFAF_1 3 Stopped"
```

Split by words

```
L = string:tokens("Process Pid Mello No Status 122 523 GFAF_0 1 Running 125 512 GFAF_235 2 Running 128 987 GFAF_1 3 Stopped", " ").

["Process","Pid","Mello","No","Status","122","523","GFAF_0",
 "1","Running","125","512","GFAF_235","2","Running","128",
 "987","GFAF_1","3","Stopped"]
```

and check if element contains "GFAF_" prefix

```
F = fun(Elem, Acc) ->
    case string:find(Elem, "GFAF_", trailing) of
      nomatch -> Acc;
      _ -> [Elem|Acc]
    end end,
  lists:foldl(F, [], L).
```

You will receive list

```
["GFAF_1","GFAF_235","GFAF_0"]
```

Comment: Thank you, solution with splitting by words is something I was looking for.